# Is this logic possible in ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Lets suppose here are smartcontract A and B. B is deployed already and has BuyService function. User need to call this function to get service with tokens. A has enough `tokens(Erc20)`.

1. User send TX to A
2. A call B's BuyService
3. B receive `tokens(erc20)` in A and give service to User

Is this logic possible? If not, how can I make A? I dont want to change the code in B. B is very general. Pls correct me.

```
contract A {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(0x...);
    B b = B(0x...);

    function helpMeBuyService() external {

        token.approve(b, 1000); 
        b.BuyService(msg.sender); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

interface B {
    function BuyService(address receiver) external;
}

interface ERC20 {
    function approve(address receiver, uint256 amout) external;
}

contract A {
    ERC20 public token = ERC20(0x123);
    B public b = B(0x123);

    function helpMeBuyService() external {
        token.approve(address(b), 1000); 
        b.BuyService(msg.sender); 
    }
}
```